# Query to select record of last five days but in between a specific time

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select rows from `mdl_logstore_standard_log`, the condition is `timecreated` should be in between last five days 7.30 AM to 4.30PM. How can I achive the combination last 5 days and the time. This is what I have

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
GROUP by userid
```

`timecreated` is in unixtimestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way too

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log 
WHERE timecreated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
      AND ( 
          (timecreated % 86400) 
             BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 07:30') 
                 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 16:30') 
      )
GROUP by userid
```

---

**`timecreated % 86400`** would return the residue in seconds.

And if the residue lies between `1970-01-01 07:30` and `1970-01-01 16:30` then your condition is actually met.

**Note:**

- Using `GROUP BY` without aggregate function is discouraged.
  (@scaisEdge already stated that)
- If you approach this way you take advantage from index on
  `timecreated` field (if any)

Answer (score 0):

PLS try this

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) >= FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))
GROUP by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use time

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
AND  time(FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated))  
      between time('2016-01-01 07:30:00.0000' ) and  time('2016-01-01 16:30:00.0000' )
GROUP by userid
```

NB you are using group by without aggregation function .. this could retrive not coherent result ..